# The proof of the fact that the summation of infinitesimal forces distributed on an object equal to the sum of concentrated external forces on it

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, integration, calculus

When concentrated external forces is applied to an object, the integration of infinitesimal forces (df) distributed on the whole object due to these concentrated forces is equal to the sum of these concentrated external forces by magnitude and direction. Is there any proof for this fact? many people see it's right by intuition or simple logic, but i dont see this is enough. Does any one have an answer for this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: By definition of an integral, it is the summation of infinitesimal elements, be these forces or anything else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The sum of all external forces acting on all the particles is equal to the total external force applied to the system of particles. Why?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/377361)

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about Newton's 2nd law: $$\sum \vec F=m\vec a$$ This is an empirical relationship; found from many, many experiments. It has never been and can't be proven. It can only be disproven - called falsification; a million examples can't prove the law to be true, but one single counter example would be enough to disprove it.

Noone  has ever succeeded in finding one counter example to disprove it within standard size scales and speeds. Therefore we believe it to be true. And we upgrade it to be called a **law of nature.**

That  you mention an integral $\int$ rather than a sum $\sum$ does not matter. The integral symbol is just how we write a summation when there are infinitely many pieces to sum up. $\int$ and $\sum$ mean the same thing; we are just lucky to have some mathematical tools when things are infinitely many or infinitesimal, and therefore it makes sense to use a different symbol such as $\int$ in such cases.

Comment: I am not talking about Newton's second law, I have edited the text of the question, please read it again, you may get my point, thank you any way.

Comment: Does the last paragraph not answer that question? To "integrate" is mathematically the same thing as to "sum". We just call it integration when there are infinitely many pieces to sum. So there is no proof here - integration is the same as summation by definition. It is just a name for the special case of summation. @صهيبأبوريدة

Comment: But why are the infinitesimal forces distributed in a way that there sum is equal to the external concentrated force, can't they be for some reason distributed in a way that there sum is not equal to the external concentrated force?

Comment: Because of the [superposition principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle): "*the net response caused by two or more stimuli is the sum of the responses that would have been caused by each stimulus individually*" Experiments/observation shows that forces behave like mathematical vectors, who obey superposition.